Show that adding cosines with different frequencies implies the frequencies are the same
How can I show that the following is true?

For all $n \in \mathbb{N},$ and $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$, if $a_i \neq 0$ for all $0<i\leq n$, and if  $$a_1 \cos{(b_1 x)} + a_2\cos{(b_2 x)} + a_3 \cos{(b_3 x)} + ... + a_n \cos{(b_n x)} = 0$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then for every $b_i$ there exists some $b_k$ such that $|b_i| = |b_k|$.

Ideas:
In general, we can proceed by contradiction and assume that at least one pair is distinct. Furthermore, the non-distinct ones can just be added to form a new single term: $a_j \cos(b_j x) + a_k \cos(b_k x) = (a_j + a_k) \cos(b_j x)$ if $b_j=b_k.$ Therefore, we can assume WLOG that every $b$ is distinct.

You can show easily show that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\ b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n \\ b_1^2 & b_2^2 & ... & b_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ b_n^{n-1} & b_2^{n-1} & ... & b_n^{n-1} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}=0$$
Now, because $\vec{a}$ is not zero, we know that the determinant of that matrix must be zero.

Another idea would be to proceed by induction; the cases $n=1, 2$ are easy but I am not sure if this is feasible.

Finally, I think the easiest approach would probably be to view this as a Fourier series, and if each cosine is viewed as a vector, we just need to use the usual inner product to show that each of those are linearly independent vectors for distinct $b_j.$ The problem, though, is that because the $b$s are reals, there is no convenient integral limits to choose. One strategy might be to approximate the $b$s by rational numbers, and then choose the appropriate integral limits, and show that any error can be made arbitrarily small. I do not know for sure if this would work.

I cannot make any of the above ideas work, and it also feels like there should be a simple and elegant way to do this.

How about $a_i, b_i$ are they reals or integers

Then I don't understand the conclusion of the problem statement, which has $b_1=b_2=\ldots = b_n\pm 2\pi m$. The $\pm 2\pi m$ allows for distinctness, yes?

Now the statement is false.

If you're not assuming distinctness, take $a_1=a_3=1$, $a_2=a_4=-1$, $b_1=b_2=1$, $b_3=b_4=2$, so we get $$(1)\cos(1\cdot x)+(-1)\cos(1\cdot x)+(1)\cos(2\cdot x)+(-1)\cos(2\cdot x)=0+0=0.$$

I think the conclusion should be that $|b_j|=|b_k|$ rather than $b_j=b_k$, because the problem doesn't change if we replace $b_j$ with $-b_j$.

For reference, such a matrix is known as a Vandermonde matrix.

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and real numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots, b_n$.  Let $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\cos(b_kx).$$  Note that $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\cos(|b_k|x).$$  Let $$F=\{|b_k|:k\in\{1,\ldots, n\}\}$$ and for each $f\in F$, let $$B_f=\{i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}:|b_i|=f\}.$$  Note that $$g=\sum_{f\in F}\Bigl[\cos(fx)\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i\Bigr].$$

Then $g\equiv 0$ iff for each $f\in F$, $\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i=0$.

Proof: Assume that for each $f\in F$, $\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i=0$. Then $$g=\sum_{f\in F}\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i\cos(b_ix)=\sum_{f\in F}\Bigl[\cos(fx)\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i\Bigr]=\sum_{f\in F}[\cos(fx)\cdot 0]=0.$$
Now assume $g\equiv 0$. We proceed by induction on $|F|$. If $F$ is a singleton, say $F=\{\phi\}$, we have $$\sum_{i\in B_\phi}a_i\cos(\phi x)=\cos(\phi x)\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i=g\equiv 0.$$ Setting $x=0$ gives $\sum_{i\in B_\phi}a_i=0$.
Assume that we have the result for each set with cardinality at most $p$ and $|F|=p+1$. Let $\phi=\max F$ and $G=F\setminus \{\phi\}$, so $|G|=p$. Seeking a contradiction, assume that $\sum_{i\in B_\phi}a_i\neq 0$.  Since $\lim_m (f/\phi)^m=0$ for each $f\in G$, there exists an even integer $m$ so large that $$\phi^m > \frac{1}{\Bigl|\sum_{i\in B_\phi} a_i\Bigr|}\sum_{f\in G}\sum_{i\in B_f}|a_i|f^m.$$ Then $$0=\bigl|\frac{d^m g}{dx^m}(0)\bigr|\geqslant \phi^m\Bigl|\sum_{i\in B_\phi}a_i\Bigr|-\sum_{f\in G}\sum_{i\in B_f}f^m |a_i|>0,$$ a contradiction. So $\sum_{i\in B_\phi}a_i=0$.  Therefore $$g=\cos(\phi x)\sum_{i\in B_\phi} a_i + \sum_{f\in G}\Bigl[\cos(f x)\sum_{i\in B_f} a_i\Bigr]=\cos(\phi x)\cdot 0+ \sum_{f\in G}\Bigl[\cos(f x)\sum_{i\in B_f} a_i\Bigr]= \sum_{f\in G}\Bigl[\cos(f x)\sum_{i\in B_f} a_i\Bigr].$$ now apply the induction hypothesis to $G$ to deduce that $\sum_{i\in B_f}a_i=0$ for the remaining $f\in G$.
If we now assume that each $a_i$ is non-zero, then each member of $F$ must be repeated. Therefore for each $i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, there exists at least one $j\neq i\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ such that $|b_i|=|b_j|$.

Your proof should work. The relevant matrix is called a Vandermonde matrix and has a well-known formula for its determinant. You get a contradiction:
$$
\det 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\ b_1 & b_2 & ... & b_n \\ b_1^2 & b_2^2 & ... & b_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ b_n^{n-1} & b_2^{n-1} & ... & b_n^{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = \prod_{i<k} (b_k - b_i) \ne0
$$
In other words, the fact that the $b_i$ are distinct contradicts the fact that the determinant of the Vandermonde matrix must be zero.
By the way, it's probably easier to start by proving that complex-valued functions of form $e^{i b_k x}$ are linearly independent, and then prove your statement about cosines.

Thanks, I didn’t realize that determinant was known and so simple. My original question actually came from musings about $e^{i b_k x}.$ I am getting a vague memory of the Wronskian. To show linear independence of the exponential functions is equivalent to looking at the Wronskian, which is equivalent to what you have above, no?

Right, the matrix is the related to the Wronskian of the exponentials evaluated at $x=0$. (The $k$th row is multiplied by a factor of $i^k$, but that doesn't change the conclusion). The reason to prefer exponentials is that for cosines the odd derivatives are zero at $x=0$.
